# Can't figure out how to scrape an ID with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape a site with an ID but I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= "Website"
page= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all ('div', class_="position-relative")

for list in lists:
    Value = list.find('h5', id_= "player_value")
print (Value)
```

Now with that it will just print:

```
None
```

Here is what the website inspect mode looks like:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: FYI read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for several reasons why it's important to post formatted text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `_` from attribute parameter `id`:

```
.find('h5', id= "player_value")
```

Why `_` is needed for the `class` from the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

> “class”, is a reserved word in Python. Using class as a keyword
> argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you
> can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_

###### Example

Assuming that there is an unique id you could get your value directly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<h5 id="player_value">1</h5>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

player_value = soup.find('h5', id= "player_value").text
print(player_value)
```

If the id of your `<h5>` is not unique and you want to get all - Avoid also to use other reserved words like `list`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<h5 id="player_value">1</h5>
<h5 id="player_value">2</h5>
<h5 id="player_value">3</h5>
<h5 id="player_value">4</h5>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for l in soup.find_all('h5', id = "player_value"):
    print (l.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the class in a dict, try that:

```
lists = soup.find_all ('div', {'class': 'position-relative'})
```

Comment: In this specific case it is just an alternative syntax for `soup.find_all('div', class_="position-relative")` - Do you checked twice, that this would fix the issue?

Comment: You are rigth! I've always selected elements this way, so I wrongly assumed it would be the only way. Great to learn new things! But I belive that passing the id as a dict like: ('h5', {"id" :"player_value"}) would also solve his problens, rigth?

Comment: Yes, the solution for id should be focus of your answer, while it causes the issue.